# Assigning TO_CHAR result to VARCHAR2, NVARCHAR2

Tags: sql, oracle, to-char, varchar2

1) In Oracle, can I store result of TO_CHAR  to VARCHAR2, NVARCHAR2? 
It seems Yes, according to below code, though.

```
CREATE TABLE TBL (  
  R1 VARCHAR2(15),    
  R2 NVARCHAR2(15), 
  R3 NVARCHAR2(15)  
  );
INSERT INTO TBL(R1, R2) VALUES (TO_CHAR(15,'999.999'),TO_CHAR(20,'999.999'));
SELECT R1+10, R2+20 FROM TBL;
```

2) Adding 10 to the VARCHAR2, NVARCHAR2 column where TO_CHAR results are stored works as above. Could I Know why  TO_NUMBER(R1), TO_NUMBER(R2) are unnecessary?

Comment: It's due to implicit conversion - Oracle will attempt to convert strings to numbers by itself if it comes across a mismatch in the data types. In fact, Oracle will always try to convert less-restrictive datatypes into the more restrictive datatypes (which can get you into trouble, as it relies on NLS parameters, e.g comparing a string to a date will try to convert the string to a date, based on the nls_date_format parameter. If your string isn't in that format, it could very well fail.)

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, because `TO_CHAR(number)` return `VARCHAR2` type, and
2. Because Oracle implicit convert your data from `VARCHAR2` to `NVARCHAR2`, or from `VARCHAR2/ NVARCHAR2` to `NUMBER`

> Oracle Database automatically converts a value from one datatype to another when such a conversion makes sense.

You could refer to [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements002.htm#i46862) for matrix of Oracle implicit conversions.